# Intel x64 assembly function called from C program how to modify arguments passed by reference

Tags: assembly, x86, 64-bit, x86-64, calling-convention

I try to modify some of arguments passed to my assembly function in C program.
I have tried it already in x86 assembly but in x64 it doesn't seem to work anymore.

```
section .text
global f
f:
  push rbp
  mov rbp, rsp
  ;[rbp+8]  bitmap beginning address (unsigned*) ?
  ;[rbp+12] bitmap width (int*) ?
  ;[rbp+16] bitmap height (int*) ?
  ;[rbp+20] current X pos (double*) ?
  ;[rbp+24] current Y pos (double*) ?

  mov rax, [rbp+12]

  mov rcx, [rax]
  inc rcx
  mov [rax], rcx 

  mov rsp, rbp
  pop rbp
  ret
```

Comment: x86_64 has different calling conventions than x86

Comment: x86-64 uses registers (and if need be the stack) to pass parameters. You'll need to look at the [64-bit System V ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf) for the calling convention.

Comment: Well, those offsets don't look very '64-bit' to me:(

Comment: 4 bytes for a `double`? You really need to read about datatypes and calling conventions for your target platform (Win/Linux/etc.)

Comment: The [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) has links to calling convention / ABI docs, and lots of other stuff.

Comment: Which C compiler are you using? That may determine which x64 calling convention to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way arguments are passed to a function in C depends on the **calling convention**.

Here, the way you modify arguments use the x86 calling convention properties (arguments are passed via the stack). But in x86_64, the calling convention is different (and may differ depending on your compiler). Arguments are generally passed via registers so modifying the stack does not modify arguments.

You can see the [list of x86 calling convention on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#List_of_x86_calling_conventions)

Comment: He's not actually trying to modify the function args, they're pointers that he's dereferencing.  The question is just badly titled, and should be "pass by reference" or something.  He's trying to load a pointer (into `rax`) and modify the data it points to.